# Will the User ID be added to other user activity reports in the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I noticed the User ID was added to the [Teams Activity Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-beta) in Graph API [documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/commit/fe7bf7bf75e987995c7b60c33665f7bf353a10f4) over a year ago. Will the other user activity reports be updated as well?

Calling the Yammer Activity Report with reports/getYammerActivityUserDetail(period='D7') should return the user ID, but at time of writing it does not.

Comment: We don't know what Microsoft is planning. You can periodically check API changelog: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/?search=